# Where is defined the TgtOutFormat type in PDFtoolkit VCL library?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a problem to set watermark image format in the `TgtImageWatermarkTemplate` component (which is part of the Gnostice PDFtoolkit VCL library). I have the following code:

```
var
  Watermark: TgtImageWatermarkTemplate;
begin
  ...
  // create and set watermark properties
  Watermark := TgtImageWatermarkTemplate.Create;
  Watermark.ImageFormat := ofJPEG; // <- this line fails the compilation
  ...
end;
```

But it fails to compile with the following error:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(186): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ofJPEG'
>   [DCC Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(5): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'Unit1.pas'
>   Failed Elapsed time: 00:00:01.5

In which unit is the `ofJPEG` identifier declared (I think it's member of the `TgtOutFormat` enumeration)? Which unit should I add to my uses clause?

Comment: Do you have the source for the library? If so, grep for `ofJPEG` in it.

Comment: i have not source of library.i get this component from Gnostice's website: 

http://www.gnostice.com/PDFtoolkit_VCL.asp

Comment: The enum value should be changed to ifJPEG.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add PDImage to the USES Clause. The type is defined in PDIMage.pas as `TgtOutFormat = (ofBMP, ofPPM, ofPBM, ofJPEG);`

Answer (score -1):

Please include gtCstPDFDoc unit in your PAS file. The enumeration TgtImageFormat is from that.

UPDATE: The enumeration values start with if and so it is ifJPEG.